# Find if the recursive sequence is limited and monototonic.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm back with another question about sequences which we at the moment we are tought at school.

Let $a_{1} = 5$ and recursive formula $a_{n+1} = 5\sqrt{a_{n}-1} -3$ .

I think I did it right for finding if the sequence is monotoniclly growing.
$a_{n+1} \ge a_{n}$ 
After a few steps I came with a quadratic function and by calculating when this function $\le 0$, I got result that $a_{n} \in[2,17]$

I don't know if it's mathematically correct now to just say that, yes the upper limit is 17 and lower limit is 5 and yes, it is monotonically growing.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We prove by induction that the sequence is increasing.

We can check directly that $a_2\gt a_1$. Now suppose that we know that for a certain $k$ we have $a_{k+1}\gt a_k$. Then 
$$a_{k+2}=5\sqrt{a_{k+1}-1}-3\gt 5\sqrt{a_k-1}-3=a_{k+1}.$$

To show the sequence has a limit, it is enough now to show that the sequence is
bounded  above. We show by induction that $a_n\lt 101$ for all $n$. This is certainly true for $n=1$. Suppose it is true for $n=k$. We show it is true  for $n=k+1$.  We have
$$a_{k+1}=5\sqrt{a_k-1}-3\lt 5\sqrt{100}-3=47\lt 101.$$

**Remark:** Now that we know the sequence has a limit $L$, it is not hard to calculate $L$. For 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=5\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{a_n-1}-3.$$
Thus $L=5\sqrt{L-1}-3$. A little manipulation gives us a quadratic equation in $L$.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think I fully understand induction. Why did you use "k" instead of "n"? Why 101? Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: I use $k$ because I have found students have a bit less trouble understanding the logic. But if you prefer, use $n$. The trouble with $n$ is that in the assertion it gets universally quantified, and makes it harder to see that we are stepping forward one step at a time. Why $101$? Because it is plenty good enough, and finding the square root of $101-1$ is easy.  To prove the sequence is bounded it is not worthwhile to expend effort in finding a *good* bound, it is enough to find a bound that works.

Comment: Well as far as I calculated the upper limit is 17. But let's say that number 16 is upper limit. Is it possible that I assume that "an < 16"  and I calculate an+1 < 16 and I get that an < 15.44 which is still less then 16, so the by the assumption the result is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is fine in principle (I have not checked the arithmetic, and doubt it). But if you want to prove boundedness, you are going to more trouble than necessary. Soon enough, you will find $L$ and therefore find the absolute best upper bound.

Comment: Note that in fact the limit is $17$, so that is the least upper bound of our $a_n$.

Comment: I have another question. If I calculate $a_{n+1} \ge a_{n}$ for finding if the sequence is growing upwards I get in the end the solution of a quadratic function that $a_{n} \in [2,17]$. Is that enough to say that the lower limit is basically $a_{1} = 5$?

Comment: Yes, but (i) you don't need to do that to show there is a lower bound, since $a_1=5$ and the $a_n$ are increasing and (ii) you don't need to address whether there is a lower bound to show the sequence converges and (iii) as I showed in the solution, you don't need to manipulate quadratics to show the sequence is bounded above.